# What is the most "comprehensive" kanji dictionary?

Tags: kanji, dictionary

I tried a quick search among similar questions but could not find exactly what I would like to know.

In Chinese, there is a huge dictionary called [汉语大词典](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanyu_Da_Cidian) that covers more than 54600 characters (at least an edition printed in the '90s). Basically the whole set of existing Chinese characters, or at least a close approximation.

I was wondering, does something like that exist in Japanese as well? I am not talking about a list of 常用漢字 or something similar. I am wondering if there exists a comprehensive dictionary that, whether they are common or not, covers all the Chinese characters that have a Japanese reading and at least potentially could be used in Japanese as well.

I am sure the list is huge, and would be interesting to have such a reference (just think of all the kanji of animals, plants, and so on).

EDIT: After some comments I decided to edit the title. I know that there is no such thing as a "complete" kanji dictionary (neither in Chinese nor Japanese) since kanji are constantly evolving and new ones may be created. I was asking just for the "most comprehensive" source out there.

Comment: There's no such thing as a complete dictionary in Chinese either, by the way.  People are still making new characters.

Comment: Yes I know that. However, given the comments I decided to edit the title and the question just to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English Wikipedia page on [kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#Total_number_of_kanji) claims that the [**Dai Kan-wa Jiten** (大漢和辞典) (Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dai_Kan-Wa_Jiten) is "considered to be comprehensive in Japan" and "contains about 50,000 characters".  (Side note: It also mentions an even bigger Chinese dictionary.)

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Might be what I was looking for, I will look into it better later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a publication in Japanese called 漢字源{かんじげん} which may have the information you're looking for.

There is also a website that seems to be based on it [here](http://jigen.net/kanji/20307) which has over 95,000 entries.

以下はハッタリ話。。。

More to the root of your question though, since Kanji is really a *system* of writing and not just a list of characters, I think you would need software to produce all possible Kanji.

Because it's a system, you can make new characters any time so long as they follow the rules of the system. And even then, if someone ever makes a new 部首 or something, it would just grow exponentially.

Now, if you wanted a list of all Kanji that actually *have been used*... I mean dag yo, that would be so big it would **melt your face**.

Comment: Supplemental Info: Unicode (the most widely used system of written language characters for computers) currently enumerates about 80,000 "CJK Unified Ideographs" which can be perused here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihangridindex.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know what you mean, and actually maybe I wasn't clear enough. I know there is no (there cannot be) such thing as a "complete" dictionary. I edited the question now, hope it's clearer that by "complete" I actually meant "most comprehensive".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there exist a  漢和辞典 to be called "COMPLETE" in Japan. Dictionaries evolve day by day. Perhaps you know that even the editing team of the Oxford English Dictionary has been adding **50 new words every day** to the dictionary.

We don't need a egregiously voluminous dictionary for practical purpose, and I don't think you need to be versed with the meanings and usages of more than 54,600 characters unless you are a scholar of Chinese characters.

When I look for the meaning of 漢語, I'm used to consult "字源" compiled by a famous Chinese classicist and linguist, 簡野道明, and published by Hokushinkan in 1923. It's a long-selling 漢語辞典.

"字源"  covers 10,681 basic Chinese characters and 73,369 漢語-derived idioms. The book (used one) is available for ￥6,480 through Amazon.

The other recommendation, though I don't own it by myself, is "字通" compiled by Dr.白河静 and published by Heibon-sha, which is also available for ￥10,800（new one) or ￥23,657 (big size) from Amazon.

Comment: Thank you for the references. Maybe you were replying as I was editing my question, just to make clear that I know there is no such thing as a "complete" kanji dictionary (there cannot be). That's why I also changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

All info about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters
I own a Taiwanese version of 中華字海 which is similar in character number to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhonghua_Zihai

(85,568)

But Morohashi Japanese Edition and its Taiwanese translation (10 volume set) is the most comprehensive and correct when definitions matter.